# LaTeX keeps calling my tables Tab. 0.1 instead of Table 1

Tags: tables, miktex, enumerate

I'm trying to draw a table in my thesis. Although I made it, but I have difficulty to enumerate that. I want to call it Table 1, but \LaTeX keeps calling it Tab. 0.1.
This is the piece of code that I'm using:

These are the packages that I'm using in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, oneside]{thesis}

\usepackage{lineno}         
\usepackage{hyperref}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}         
\usepackage{multirow}       
\usepackage{multicol}       
\usepackage{epstopdf}       
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{0.9\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill} } | c | c | c | c | c | }
\hline
Time - Angle & $45^{\circ}$ & $90 ^{\circ}$ & $180^{\circ} $ &  $360^{\circ}$ \\
\hline 
0.5 s & 44.22  & 192.71 & 1002.9  & 4118.2\\
\hline
1 s & 12.68 & 41.33  &  157.81 & 650.87 \\
\hline
2 s & 7.14 & 23.47 & 72.51 & 182.65\\
\hline
4 s & 4.41 &  14.43 & 32.05 & 109.12 \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\caption{My caption}
\label{Table:1}
\end{table}
```

Comment: This is not the default behaviour. Could you expand on your current code snippet in such a way that the problem can be reproduced? You may be using packages as part of your thesis template that is causing this. Without much more we can only speculate on what is causing this.

Comment: You are probably using the `report` class and gave no `\chapter` command

Comment: look to see whether there is a line `\numberwithin{table}{...}` in your preamble.  if there is, remove it.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you use.

Comment: @Werner, I edited the question to clarify my issue! Thanks.

Comment: @egreg I'm using Thesis document class!

Comment: @Milad There are uncountably many `Thesis` document classes around. Check whether it loads `report.cls` or `book.cls`. In any case, it seems you're expected to use `\chapter` as main subdivision.

Comment: @egreg I didn't find neither book.cls or report.cls!

Comment: Off topic:  `hyperref` should be loaded after almost all other packages.  The exceptions are noted in the documentation for those packages.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the class expects you're using `\chapter` as the main subdivision.

However, you can work around the issue by adding

```
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
```

just like you're doing for figures. Add also

```
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Table}
```

in order to have “Table 1” instead of “Tab. 1”.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But it still keeps calling them Tab. 1 instead of Table 1! Do you know to fix that?

Comment: @Milad Added; try it

Comment: I tried \renewcommand{\tablename}{Table 1}, not working!

Comment: @Milad Perhaps `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Table}}}` (the class possibly loads `babel`).

Comment: It's really weird! It's not doing anything!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
\renewcommand{\figureshortname}{Figure}
```

And in case you also have to use figures, use:

```
\renewcommand{\tableshortname}{Table}
```

Comment: Which document class do you use? Does the proposed method work with the document class that's used by the OP?

Comment: As it stands this not yet an answer, in my point of view

Comment: This looks like it will work for the [`thesis`](http://ctan.org/pkg/thesis) class found on CTAN.

Comment: After a lots of search on the internet and using so many suggestions, this worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, oneside]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{0.9\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill} } | c | c | c | c | c | }
\hline
Time - Angle & $45^{\circ}$ & $90 ^{\circ}$ & $180^{\circ} $ &  $360^{\circ}$ \\
\hline 
0.5 s & 44.22  & 192.71 & 1002.9  & 4118.2\\
\hline
1 s & 12.68 & 41.33  &  157.81 & 650.87 \\
\hline
2 s & 7.14 & 23.47 & 72.51 & 182.65\\
\hline
4 s & 4.41 &  14.43 & 32.05 & 109.12 \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\caption{My caption}
\label{Table:1}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

% You do not need any packages. This works well

Comment: The problem desribed by the OP clearly is related to their use of a documentclass called `thesis`. In your example, you switched to a different documntclass that exhibits a different default behaviour.

Comment: To improve the readability of the code in your answers, you might want to take a look at [How do I mark code blocks?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192/134144)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Many of my students wrote thesis in physics using documentclass{article}. For research publications, we down loaded the style and class packages and without understanding them.  None of my students used  documentclass{thesis}. I will study your suggestions of code blocks. Thanks for the suggestion.